# @RestController with swagger codegen maven plugin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger-codegen

I am using swagger-codegen-maven-plugin (2.2.2) to generate API and model classes from inputSpec. The language is Spring and library is spring-boot.

The API class which swagger is generating is annotated with @Controller annotation, is there any configOption with which this can be changed to annotate the API class with @RestController instead ?

**Tech Stack**

Spring Boot - 2.2.5
Java - JDK 11
Maven - 3.6.1
swagger-codegen-maven-plugin-version - 2.2.2

````
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger-codegen-maven-plugin-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${input_spec_file}</inputSpec>
                            <language>spring</language>
                            <apiPackage>${api.package}</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>${model.package}</modelPackage>
                            <templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/codegen-templates</templateDirectory>
                            <configOptions>
                                <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                                <skipOverwrite>true</skipOverwrite>
                                <java8>true</java8>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                            </configOptions>
                            <output>.</output>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>```


Thanks in advance..!!
````

Comment: Refer this article    https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-rest-client-swagger-codegen

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
                <language>java</language>
                <library>resttemplate</library>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and for dependency add this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.baeldung</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-swagger-codegen-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Shubham, but the language for me have to be spring, and the libraries supported with are spring-boot, spring-mvc and spring-cloud.